# ionic v4 and social-sharing plugin

Tags: angular, ionic4, share

I've a working custom component where I've just added a share button. I'd like to make it work, so I've installed [this social sharing plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/social-sharing/) and I've followed the seemingly simple instructions, e.g.

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/social-sharing@4
```

However, as soon as I inject the required service into the constructor, the app stops working and I get an error in the browser console (see below). Here is a snippet from the `.ts` file of my custom component with the import and the property injection I added to the constructor. Please note I've cut several parts of the real code that are useless as long as this issue is concerned:

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit, ElementRef, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import { PdfParametersService } from '../../services/pdf-parameters.service';
import { UserProfileService } from '../../services/user-profile.service';
import { SocialSharing } from '@ionic-native/social-sharing';

@Component({
  selector: 'sollecita',
  templateUrl: './sollecita.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sollecita.component.scss'],
})
export class SollecitaComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  constructor(
              private socialSharing: SocialSharing, /* THIS LINE TRIGGERS THE PROBLEM */
              private service: PdfParametersService,
              private profileService: UserProfileService
              ) {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  }
```

And here is the error I get in the browser console, only when there is the social sharing service injected into the constructor. If I comment out that line, the app starts working again, but it obviously lacks sharing capabilities:

```
 Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: Cannot access 'SollecitaPageModule' before initialization
ReferenceError: Cannot access 'SollecitaPageModule' before initialization
    at Module.SollecitaPageModule (VM609 pages-sollecita-sollecita-module.js:890)
    at VM44 main.js:2141
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (VM37 polyfills.js:3604)
    at Object.onInvoke (VM45 vendor.js:79927)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (VM37 polyfills.js:3603)
    at Zone.run (VM37 polyfills.js:3363)
    at VM37 polyfills.js:4090
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (VM37 polyfills.js:3639)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (VM45 vendor.js:79908)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (VM37 polyfills.js:3638)
    at Zone.runTask (VM37 polyfills.js:3407)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (VM37 polyfills.js:3809)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (VM37 polyfills.js:3724)
    at invokeTask (VM37 polyfills.js:4835)
    at HTMLElement.globalZoneAwareCallback (VM37 polyfills.js:4861)
    at resolvePromise (VM37 polyfills.js:4032) [angular]
    at resolvePromise (VM37 polyfills.js:3991) [angular]
    at :8100/polyfills.js:4093:21 [angular]
    at Object.onInvokeTask (VM45 vendor.js:79908) [angular]
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (VM37 polyfills.js:3809) [<root>]
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (VM37 polyfills.js:3724) [<root>]
    at invokeTask (VM37 polyfills.js:4835) [<root>]
    at HTMLElement.globalZoneAwareCallback (VM37 polyfills.js:4861) [<root>]
defaultErrorLogger @ core.js:6014
handleError @ core.js:6066
next @ core.js:40558
schedulerFn @ core.js:35336
__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:183
next @ Subscriber.js:122
_next @ Subscriber.js:72
next @ Subscriber.js:49
next @ Subject.js:39
emit @ core.js:35298
(anonymous) @ core.js:39738
invoke @ zone-evergreen.js:365
run @ zone-evergreen.js:124
runOutsideAngular @ core.js:39572
onHandleError @ core.js:39735
handleError @ zone-evergreen.js:369
runGuarded @ zone-evergreen.js:137
api.microtaskDrainDone @ zone-evergreen.js:671
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone-evergreen.js:577
invokeTask @ zone-evergreen.js:485
invokeTask @ zone-evergreen.js:1596
globalZoneAwareCallback @ zone-evergreen.js:1622
```

And here is my `SollecitaPageModule.ts` code:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

import { SollecitaPageRoutingModule } from './sollecita-routing.module';

import { SollecitaPage } from './sollecita.page';

import { SollecitaComponent } from '../../../components/sollecita/sollecita.component';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    SollecitaPageRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [SollecitaPage, SollecitaComponent]
})
export class SollecitaPageModule {}
```

I don't understand why SollecitaPageModule is being affected by the injection of the sharing service in the component. I suspect the culprit is the way I import and/or the way I declare the component in the page module, but, even then, I don't know why and I don't know how to fix it. Can you help please?

Comment: Which version of Ionic are you using? You mentioned Ionic 4 in your title but you are following the implementation of Ionic 3 for this plugin. For v4: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/social-sharing

Comment: Please kill me, here and now. Someone has to stop me doing stupid things. How can I undo the wrong `npm` command?

Comment: No worries! You're still using the same cordova plugin and and npm package, but you need the newest version. Just run "npm install @ionic-native/social-sharing" and I think it should update properly. And in your app.module.ts you need to import "import { SocialSharing } from '@ionic-native/social-sharing/ngx';" and SocialSharing in your providers.